# Simulating get filter criteria- Error | Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I have a function that one of the users suggested to get the criterion of the built-in google sheets filter. I dont know if I'm doing it right but when I paste the `getVisibleValues()` function to the cell I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getColumnFilterCriteria' of undefined
> (row18)

```
function test_getVisibleValues() {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test1");
      const columnRange = sheet.getRange("C2:C");
      const filter = columnRange.getFilter();
      const visibleValues = getVisibleValues(filter, columnRange);
      console.log(visibleValues);
    }
    /**
     * Returns the values to show.
     * Simulates https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria#getvisiblevalues
     * @param {Filter} filter
     * @param {Range} range
     * @returns {string[]}
     */
    function getVisibleValues(filter, range) {
      const filterCriteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(range.getColumn());
      const hiddenValues = filterCriteria.getHiddenValues();
      const allNonBlankValues = range.getValues().filter(String);
      const uniqueValues = Array.from(new Set(allNonBlankValues));
          
      // filter unique values that aren't hidden
      return uniqueValues.flat().filter(value => !hiddenValues.includes(value));
    }
```

Comment: Assuming that you have a sheet with the name `Test1` the issue might be that your selected range ( column C) does not have a filter and as a result `getFilter()` returns null. Can you confirm that ? Also try C1:C instead to get the full column.

Comment: @Marios The C column contains a filter. I tried C1: C and the same error. 
Am I doing this correctly by typing =getVisibleValues() without any parameters?

Comment: which function are you executing first? `test_getVisibleValues` or `getVisibleValues`. If you execute the latter, then the arguments are not defined and hence the error. I tested your code by executing `test_getVisibleValues` and it didn't generate any error. I think it is straightforward to understand. The function `getVisibleValues` requires two arguments: `filter` and `range`. If you execute **first** the `getVisibleValues` then the arguments are **not** defined anywhere. But if you execute `test_getVisibleValues` first, then you pass these arguments to `getVisibleValues` and then it works.

Comment: @Marios hmm so how can i use the whole by typing a function into a cell to return a result ?

Comment: Check my answer. I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Your goal is to use your code as a custom function so it can be used as a formula in your sheet.

**Solution:**

Make sure column `C` contains a filter and that this formula applies to the sheet `Test1`. Change these to your needs or use:

`const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()`

if you want to get the active sheet instead.

```
function test_getVisibleValues(rng) {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    const range = sheet.getRange(rng);
    const filter = range.getFilter();
    const filterCriteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(range.getColumn());
    const hiddenValues = filterCriteria.getHiddenValues();
    const allNonBlankValues = range.getValues().filter(String);
    const uniqueValues = Array.from(new Set(allNonBlankValues));          
    // filter unique values that aren't hidden
    return uniqueValues.flat().filter(value => !hiddenValues.includes(value));
}
```

You can now apply `test_getVisibleValues("C2:C")` as a formula in your sheet but `C2:C` needs to be inside quotation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!, it almost works There is only one problem do you know how to make a function dynamic? because after changing the filter criterion the result does not change

Comment: @AdOne Unfortunately, this is a limitation by google and there is not a solution to this but only workarounds. You can get some ideas [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69722/how-do-i-refresh-script-results-when-a-cell-color-is-changed).